# Chinese transliterated place names

Tags: place-names, database

I am looking for a database of place names which would be non-Chinese place names listing their transliteration into Chinese. When I view Google Maps on my iPhone with the phone language set to Chinese, it provides a Chinese name for every small town and city. I anticipate this data must be avaliable somewhere potentially through a free data source or API for map developers.

I don't know a lot about GPS data and the data which feeds map labeling like this, but I did find [this site for GNIS data](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/board-on-geographic-names/download-gnis-data). I've tried searching many terms including "GNIS data" and "Chinese" but I am always finding only Chinese names of Chinese places. Hoping to find something which is basically these files but in Chinese.

Does anyone have an idea where I could find this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the national academy for educational research, of taiwan  maintained a file “   外國地名譯名壓縮檔”, the direct link is:

https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/380/Term_380.zip/

it’s a zip file containing several excel files, each row has the original location name in english, name in chinese, latitude & longitude.

indeed, the download area have files of most disciplines, of terms in chinese & foreign languages:

https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/

the only caveat is, the page is in traditional chinese only

Comment: Thanks so much! I was aware of this website but had totally missed that file. Much appreciated!

Comment: @swerveken, you’re welcome, have fun to play with these files  though i can’t prove, i suspected google map data is from it 